# Effective mass of Ellis wormholes

Tags: relativity, wormholes

[Ellis wormholes are (described as) curved in space only, with no component of their curvature in the time part of spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellis_wormhole). The geometry therefore causes no gravity.

If my understanding of relativity is correct (a big if), two observers in different frames of reference disagree about alignment of the space-axis and the time-axis, and therefore it follows that the previous statement about "curved in space only" can only be valid from one frame of reference, presumably the rest frame of the Ellis wormhole.

This implies that an Ellis wormhole has a gravitational field, but *only* for observers in a different frame of reference.

My grasp of relativity is sadly insufficient to follow the maths in the linked Wikipedia page. Is my understanding correct? Would an Ellis wormhole have an apparent mass that varies depending on the observer's frame of reference?

Comment: Wiki states, "*There being no gravity in force, an inertial observer (test particle) can sit forever at rest at any point in space*". Thus in any other frame the relative movement of the particle would be caused only by the movement of this frame. In an accelerating frame, there would be an apparent gravity per the equivalence principle, but this would not give any mass to the wormhole just like it does not give any mass to the flat empty space. So this wormhole does not have a gravitational field on its own in any frame just like the Earth has the same gravitational acceleration in any frame.

Comment: @safesphere How can this be reconciled with different frames of reference disagreeing with each other about both space intervals and time intervals (only agreeing about *combined* spacetime intervals)?

Comment: If a test particle is at rest near the wormhole in the rest frame, in which frame would this particle appear falling into the wormhole? In none. In any frame the particle still will be at rest relative to the wormhole. You can choose an accelerating frame, in which the particle would seem under gravity of acceleration, but still not under gravity of the wormhole. A gravitational curvature of spacetime is a tensor. It is either there or not. Tensors don't disappear or reappear depending on the frame. Your initial assumption that gravity of the wormhole depended on the frame was incorrect.

Comment: @safesphere You appear to have misunderstood what I was asking you to reconcile. What happens if the test particle *is not at rest*?

Comment: @safesphere Separately — and this is where my knowledge of the maths is totally insufficient and I know it — I don't believe I am claiming the tensor appears or disappears or even changes invariants, I'm asking if the elements of the curvature that are purely spacial from the point of view of an observer at rest are mixed between space-and-time for an observer in relative motion.

Comment: At rest or not makes no difference. The point is that the value of the momentum of the particle does not change, because there is no gravity force to change it. (The direction may change due to the space curvature, but the energy stays the same.) In an accelerating frame, the value of the relative momentum would change due to the frame acceleration, but not to gravity. A gravity tensor is a physical object with physical properties. Just like a planet, it may have different coordinates (components) in different frames, but this does not change its nature. It either causes gravity or it doesn't.

Comment: Let me put it this way. A spacelike interval in one frame is spacelike in any frame. There is no frame, in which this interval would be timelike. Similarly, if there is no time curvature in one frame, there is none in any frame.

Comment: @safesphere OK, got it. That's a massive surprise, given that basically all of the introductions to relativity make a massive effort to demonstrate that length is dilated and time is dilated but (when they're one step up from basic) that the combination of the two (+--- or -+++) is not dilated, but given what you've said, your explanation has at least managed to improve my understanding. Thanks! :)

Comment: There is a lot of criticism of "rubber sheet" gravity diagrams, as if "incorrect", because it is impossible to show the 4D curvature on a 2D projection of a 3D diagram: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d1/GPB_circling_earth.jpg - And people don't get what the depth on the sheet represents. So now you can see that the sheet represents the curvature of time, because the curvature of space does not cause gravity (flat sheet for this wormhole) and the depth on the sheet represents the speed of time (the lower the slower).

Comment: @safesphere That's not so helpful. I totally get the rubber sheet is just a lies-to-kids version of it, but I'm still just accepting-as-true without groking anything when you write that a spacelike interval is always spacelike from all non-accelerating frames: this still seems incompatible everyone else saying one observer can observe that two events are separated in space only while a different observer (non-accelerating but moving relative to the first) observes the events separated in both time and (a different amount of) space.

Comment: You didn't get my point. The rubber sheet is not a lie-to-kids version, as everyone thinks, but the exact representation of gravitational time dilation, which is the source of gravity. The rubber sheet for your wormhole is flat. Also, a spacelike interval is spacelike in any frame, accelerating or not.

Comment: @safesphere The rubber sheet version of the Elis wormhole — well, of almost every wormhole, including two-way-traversable and the black-hole-white-hole-pair type, because all of them are drawn almost indistinguishably — has two parallel flat regions at different depths. You're telling me that the speed of time is different in two flat regions.

Comment: @safesphere "Also, a spacelike interval is spacelike in any frame, accelerating or not." — I remember you saying so. I'm *blindly accepting it*. The problem is I'm looking at this animation, and failing to understand how this is *compatible with relativity of simultaneity*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Relativity_of_Simultaneity_Animation.gif

Comment: Taking the simplest Minkowski metric $d\tau^2=dt^2-dr^2$, the interval is spacelike when $dr>dt$ thus making the proper time $\tau$ imaginary. On the diagram the angle between this interval and the time axis is more than $45^o$. Changing the frame via the Lorentz transformation skews the diagram by up to $\pm 45^o$. This is not enough to put this interval inside the light cone, so the interval remains spacelike in any frame. If the interval is timelike in one frame, a signal can cross it with a subluminal speed. In no frame this speed becomes superluminal, so the interval type is invariant.

Comment: The rubber sheet analogy can represent gravity or something else, such as space curvature that has nothing to do with gravity. These two analogies are separate, unrelated, and must not be confused with each other. With gravity, the rubber sheet of the Ellis wormhole is flat in polar coordinates where radius $\rho$ measures the distance from the central circle at the throat. And because the wormhole connects two spatial regions, each would have its own flat rubber sheet connected to the other at $\rho=0$. So gravity is represented by two flat rubber sheets connected at the central point.

Comment: The Ellis wormhole diagram in Wiki does not represent gravity. It represents a curved space and does this rather approximately, because it s not clear what the coordinates are. This has nothing to do with gravity or time. Gravity is zero everywhere and the speed of time accordingly is the same everywhere in both regions.

Comment: @safesphere Thanks. I want to see if I now understand correctly by rephrasing that. I think I've been looking at the wrong set of axies when thinking about timelike and spacelike intervals; contrast what I have been thinking {dr == spacelike, dt == timelike} with what I should be thinking {subluminal == timelike, superluminal == spacelike}. Does this sound like both my mistake and your correction of it?

Comment: Yes, "subliminal" and "superluminal" would be essentially correct in any frame, as long as you keep these definitions local. For example, in the frame of the rotating Earth, Alpha Centauri rotates around us covering 27 light years in 24 hours. This is 10,000 times the normal speed of light. Is is superluminal? Locally no, because, light emitted by Alpha Centauri over there locally would still move faster than the star itself. In contrast, light falling into a black hole slows down and stops at the event horizon in our remote frame. So anything faster would be superluminal even if only 1 mm/s.